# About the kanji 兎: can rabbit be also pronounced as "to"?

Tags: kanji, pronunciation

There is a well known personage in Japan called Tsukishiro Yukito (月城 雪兎) from Cardcaptor Sakura. Tsuki stands for moon, shiro for castle, yuki for snow and the kanji "兎" means rabbit but it sounds like "usagi" and not as "to" (the name of Yukito).

**Can rabbit be also pronounced as "to" in Japan?**

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/兎#Readings

Comment: @Chocolate Same question, can I say "to" when I refer to a rabbit or that is only applied when it comes to reading the kanji?

Answer (score 4):

Let's learn about [on- and kun-readings of kanji](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/onyomi-kunyomi/), including their history and roles. After understanding them, you can answer your own question.

In 兎's case, *usagi* is the kun-reading, which often means it can be used as a standalone word. On the other hand, *to* is the on-reading, which often implies it's a "component" rather than a standalone word. The sound *to* by itself is obviously too short, and does not work as a word meaning "rabbit" in Japanese. [There are many kanji whose on-reading is *to*](http://kanji.jitenon.jp/cat/yomi20.html). But the sound *to* appears in some longer compound words such as 脱兎.

At any rate, both are valid readings of this character, and in person names, *on* and *kun* readings are used more or less arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1):

兎 is commonly read as "うさぎ" and "と" appears as pronunciation in a compound word combined with other *kanji*.
By the way, in the following famous [proverb](http://kotowaza-allguide.com/ni/nitowooumono.html), 兎 is pronounced "と" instead of "うさぎ".

> 二兎{にと}を追｛お｝う者｛もの｝は一兎｛いっと｝（を）も得｛え｝ず
>   *If you run after two hares, you will catch neither*.

Strictly speaking, 一兎{いっと} and 二兎｛にと｝ are compound words.
If you want to find words with the same meanings by the pronunciation with うさぎ for 兎, you would get 兎{うさぎ}一羽｛いちわ｝ and 兎｛うさぎ｝二羽｛にわ｝.

Comment: In the case of 一兎 and 二兎 is ”兎" being used as a counter or are they set phrases (and as such it would be incorrect to say 三兎, 四兎, etc)?

Comment: @vel: 兎 is used as a counter in 一兎 and 二兎, so you can logically say 三兎{さんと} or 四兎｛しと｝. To tell you the truth, I've never counted rabbits/hares before, so I've never used 三兎 and 四兎 except for using 一兎 and 二兎 in the proverb. Though 兎 is used as a counter, we don't say like 一犬{いっけん} *dog*, 二猫｛にびょう｝ *cat* or 三馬｛さんば｝ *horse* but we say "犬一頭｛いぬいっとう｝", "猫二匹｛ねこにひき｝" or "馬三頭｛うまさんとう｝". When I'm writing this comment I think 兎 in 一兎 or 二兎 is a counter but it could be a counter only in the set phrases as 一兎 and 二兎 in the proverb.